# Python script using subprocess sometimes hangs randomly

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using subprocess to run ~20 powershell scripts (one after another), sometimes it hangs and I need to click enter button so script will continue its job..

Here is my code:

```
for file in files:
            process = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "{} {}".format(str(script_dir), str(root_dir)+"\\"+file)], 
                    stdout=sys.stdout)

            process.wait()
            process.communicate()
```

What could be wrong?